# Angular: How to change icons inside <mat-nav-list>?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend

I want to change icons in :

1. If list is rolled should show icon "arrow1"
2. In other cases should show icon named "arrow2".

How to check if list is rolled, and code it in html?

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item>
        <h3>Text1</h3>
        <mat-list-item>
            <a>One</a>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>
            <a>Two</a>
        </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: What type of icon you are talking about

Comment: and what do you mean by `arrow1`?

Comment: I want to use <mat-icon>, similar to: tiny.cc/kmcq9y (line 12-14 in html file). Name 'arrow1' is only example, I want to use "arrow_right" and "arrow_drop_down"

Comment: Check this demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrqffa

Comment: I want to use different icons, depends if my list is rolled or not, in your code there is two same icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should not "change" the icons, instead you can hide/show the icons based on some variables / object states. It would be a nicer approach this way (for example: because the icon-change is instant, no latency is present). I have compiled a stackblitz demo here, so you can check my version:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-63sjtx?file=app%2Flist-sections-example.html

This is how I would do the html, for example:

```
    <mat-list>
      <h3 mat-subheader>Folders</h3>
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let folder of folders; let i = index" (click)="toggleArrow(i)" class="list-item">
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon [ngClass]="folder.open ? 'hidden' : ''">arrow_right</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon [ngClass]="folder.open ? '' : 'hidden'">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
        <h4 mat-line>{{folder.name}}</h4>
        <p mat-line> {{folder.updated | date}} </p>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
```

And the typescript:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export interface Section {
  name: string;
  updated: Date;
  open: boolean
}

/**
 * @title List with sections
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'list-sections-example',
  styleUrls: ['list-sections-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'list-sections-example.html',
})
export class ListSectionsExample {
  folders: Section[] = [
    {
      name: 'Photos',
      updated: new Date('1/1/16'),
      open: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Recipes',
      updated: new Date('1/17/16'),
      open: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Work',
      updated: new Date('1/28/16'),
      open: false
    }
  ];

  toggleArrow(folderIndex) {
    this.folders[folderIndex].open = !this.folders[folderIndex].open;
  }
}
```

Lastly the CSS:

```
.mat-list-icon {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

.list-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list-item:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.list-item .hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse (deep, deep) down to the rendered element where the `mat-select-arrow` class exist and replace that with any icon of your choice; You need to do this inside `ngOnInit` so that the DOM is loaded when you do that;

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div #mySelect id="mySelect">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Select">
            <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import {Component,ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-form-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-form-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-form-example.css'],
})
export class SelectFormExample {
  @ViewChild('mySelect')mySelectElement:ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, hostElement: ElementRef) {  }

  ngOnInit(){
    let myElement = this.mySelectElement.nativeElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0];
    this.renderer.removeClass(myElement, 'mat-select-arrow');
    this.renderer.addClass(myElement, 'fas');
    this.renderer.addClass(myElement, 'fa-cat');
  }
}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-owm4yk)